# WPF How to listen to a BindingBase object?

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, datatrigger

I want to create a special `DataTrigger` inheriting the `TriggerBase<FrameworkElement>`. Just similar to the `DataTrigger`, a property of type `BindingBase` has been defined in the `MyDataTrigger` class.

How can I listen to it in order to trace its changes?

```
public class MyDataTrigger : TriggerBase<FrameworkElement>
{
    ...

    /// <summary>
    /// [Wrapper property for BindingProperty]
    /// <para>
    /// Gets or sets the binding that produces the property value of the data object.
    /// </para>
    /// </summary>
    public BindingBase Binding
    {
        get { return (BindingBase)GetValue(BindingProperty); }
        set { SetValue(BindingProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty BindingProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Binding",
                                    typeof(BindingBase),
                                    typeof(MyDataTrigger),
                                    new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null));

}
```

**Update:**

The main problem is that I don't know how to find the `BindingBase` associated `DependencyProperty`. I know how to listen to a DP;

```
void ListenToDP(object component, DependencyProperty dp)
{
    DependencyPropertyDescriptor dpDescriptor = DependencyPropertyDescriptor.FromProperty(dp, component.GetType());
    dpDescriptor.AddValueChanged(component, DPListener_ValueChanged);
}
```

Where `DPListener_ValueChanged` is an `EventHandler` delegate. Here, the *component* parameter value is `this.AssociatedObject`.

Comment: Is it true to say that the `BindingBase` associated DP is always `DataContext`?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, found!

Considering this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7666555/668342), Binding is not a DP. So I tried to find Binding associated DP:

```
Type type = Binding.GetType();
PropertyPath propertyPath = (PropertyPath)(type.GetProperty("Path").GetValue(Binding));
string propertyName = propertyPath.Path;
```

Complete code:

```
public class MyDataTrigger : TriggerBase<FrameworkElement>
{
    ...

    public BindingBase Binding
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        base.OnAttached();

        if (Binding != null && this.AssociatedObject.DataContext != null)
            //
            // Adding a property changed listener..
            //
            Type type = Binding.GetType();
            PropertyPath propertyPath = (PropertyPath)(type.GetProperty("Path").GetValue(Binding));
            string propertyName = propertyPath.Path;

            TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(this.AssociatedObject.DataContext).Find(propertyName, false).AddValueChanged(this.AssociatedObject.DataContext, PropertyListener_ValueChanged);
    }

    private void PropertyListener_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Do some stuff here..
    }
}
```

Comment: This cannot be marked as a general answer. Here the `Path` property of `BindingBase` considered only. (and for example not `XPath`). Any suggestion?

Comment: What was wrong with using... 
var propertyName = ((Binding)this.Binding).Path.Path;